# How to show and replicate documents for certain users and roles only?

Tags: couchdb, replication, acl, pouchdb, nosql

I'm building a collaboration app with couchdb and pouchdb.

I want to implement a calendar feature.

Let's say there is an event like "secret meeting" that involves the users Jessica and James, so the event should have read, update and replicate capabilities only for Jessica and James. 
Or, let's say, I have an event like "general meeting" that should have read, edit and replicate capabilities only for all current (and FUTURE!) users having the role "office".

I know that there is no per-document-access control in couchdb. 
I also read about using "proxy servers" but I don't understand how they work.

I read a lot about using "one document per user". 
How do I keep the documents in-sync in each database, then? 
I could make a DATABASE for each event, but how do I query for views  showing all my events? Do I also have to keep a database-per-role?

This is the most normal use case every web app nowadays has! 
Think Facebook, think Whatsapp, every chat app.

How should you use CouchDB if you can't limit the access to certain documents?

Comment: Have you link into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295304/per-document-user-access-control-for-pouchdb-couchdb

Comment: that thread doesn't have an answer and goes off-topic.

Comment: I think you mean "one database per user" not "one document per user". Also, CouchDB does allow per-document access, but it must be set up with a design document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selective replication with CouchDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887903/selective-replication-with-couchdb)

Comment: @Flimzy it does not allow per-document read access. Where did you read that?

Comment: @Kinesias: You're, right, there's no per-document _read_ access. There are other forms of per-document access control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up developing a PROXY server for my databases which sits in front of my main databases and filters the data. It has its own port and queries Couchdb on port 5984 for permissions. I used nodejs and the Nano couchDB adapter for that.

Comment: I'm confused. Would appreciate if you could elaborate how you solved this cuz I'm using nodejs and Nano too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have a database per user, you will use [filtered replication](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) to place into each database all the event documents related to that user or the roles that user belongs to, then you will replicate that entire DB down to the user's PouchDB.